# dircolors/ls colors not being displayed correctly using byobu

Tags: 11.04, command-line, colors, byobu

On my NAS box running Ubuntu 11.04 I'm experiencing an odd issue with dircolors inside byobu. Per the image below, everything works fine outside byobu. The prompt (zsh), vim, and everything else works fine... it's just dircolors that don't appear to be working correctly.  One additional note, in Putty on Windows and iTerm2 on OS X I'm using the [Solarized](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) color theme.

Steps I've taken to fix, inside byobu:

```
alake@foxery:~/askubuntu » dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors
alake@foxery:~/askubuntu » echo $TERM >> ~/.dircolors

### Restarted ssh session here

alake@foxery:~/askubuntu » alias ls
ls='ls --color=tty'
alake@foxery:~/askubuntu » echo $TERM && grep $TERM ~/.dircolors
screen-256color-bce
TERM screen-256color-bce
alake@foxery:~/askubuntu » dpkg -la | grep -i byobu
ii  byobu                                     3.33-0ubuntu1.1                            a set of useful profiles and a profile-switcher for GNU screen
```

**iTerm:**
[image: iTerm byobu / non-byobu dircolors difference]
**Putty:**
[image: Putty byobu / non-byobu dircolors difference]
- Overriding the alias with `ls --color=auto` doesn't work.

Comment: why are you aliasing ls to add `--color=tty` ? valid values are never, always and auto according to the manpage

Comment: The color "tty" is a valid color, but it is so very rarely used.

Comment: Did you try overriding that alias, by doing `ls --color=auto` and see if that helps?

Comment: Ah yes `ls.c` seems to have backwards compatibility support to map between those. So tty is actually equivalent to auto.

Comment: Not sure how that got in there in the first place, but it wasn't ever broke before, so why fix it. I never manually set that so it was something Ubuntu did somewhere along the line.

Comment: I've tried that as well, no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more digging I believe this is a bug with byobu, and not a configuration problem as I originally thought. I've filed bug [#817690](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/817690) in Launchpad, where it probably belongs.  Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that the `byobu` color configurations (which can sometimes get handled separately on its load) are overriding the automatic coloring of the system in `dircolors` or whatever it is.  I dont have a solution, but this might be a bug (although to be perfectly clear, I use ZSH and Bash, and running either in `byobu`/`screen` does not override my colors).  I'd recommend either filing a bug report or waiting for a while.