# How do I stop byobu from hijacking highlighting by `ls`?

Tags: command-line, byobu

I've just upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 15.04 (well, actually using KDE/Kubuntu, but it appears to be irrelevant) and I noticed colouring in the terminal is a bit messed up when using `byobu`. The most annoying one is symbolic links being colored with *blinking*. Looks like a website from the nineties.

So,

```
gert@e7240:~⟫ ln -s Desktop test
gert@e7240:~⟫ ls -l test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 gert gert 7 Apr 29 23:52 test -> Desktop
```

Then `test` from the `ls -l` output is blinking.

Why? And how can I disable this and restore the behaviour of Ubuntu 14.04 here?

It happens unrelated to the used terminal. In Konsole, xterm, etc.

Also, the highlighting of searches in `less` appears *italic* rather than highlighted before (negative).

[image]

[image]

`LS_COLORS` environment variable is different from inside and outside a byobu session:

inside:

```
env | grep -F LS_COLORS
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=38;5;5:ln=4;5;37:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=3;28:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=38;5;202:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

outside:

```
env | grep -F LS_COLORS
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
```

I like the basic highlighting without using Byobu and now I want to stop it taking over that environment variable values. How do I do that?

It looks like [this byobu change](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/5.78-0ubuntu1) introduced the behaviour (as intended mostly). But please, it's ugly and it should honour the `LS_COLORS` from the environment in my opinion.

Comment: @EliahKagan It happens on a Live CD too, also in 14.10. And no, it does not happen in a virtual terminal using the same user, same shell. I don't know where this is coming from. Perhaps some colouring by `ls` that has changed since 14.10.

Comment: Check the contents of the $LS_COLORS environment variable. If it's set, ln=__ controls the coloring for symbolic links, and blinking links would have a 5 in there, e.g. ln=5;36.

Comment: Oh, I now see it happens after using `byobu`. That changes the whole picture of this question. Let me update the question. @EliahKagan

Comment: Possibly a regression of [dircolors/ls colors not being displayed correctly using byobu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/54582/dircolors-ls-colors-not-being-displayed-correctly-using-byobu)?

Comment: @steeldriver No, it's this much newer introduced change I think: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byobu/5.78-0ubuntu1

Comment: Why not simply place the desired line `LS_COLORS` into `.byoburc` ?

Comment: @Serg I would like an answer on how to stop byobu "hijacking" the environment variable. If possible. So, just honouring that in my .bashrc, .profile, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just run:

```
byobu-disable-prompt
```

You can toggle this with:

```
byobu-enable-prompt
```

Or interactively with:

```
byobu-prompt
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Ah! I thought that was toggling the automatic start of the byobu session on terminal start. Thanks, I can test that later. P.S. The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/byobu-prompt.1.html) doesn't mention changing anything other than `PS1`, but it does.

Comment: Okay, `LS_COLORS` is indeed solved, but highlighting in manpages and `less` is still 'hijacked' compared to a non-byobu session. How do I prevent that? Instead of highlighting matches with colour inversion it puts the match in italics like displayed in the question body. It's very hard to spot the search matches that way.